# GVim tab bar: scroll tab bar instead of changing buffer on arrow click?

Tags: vim, scroll, tabs, click

I frequently have 10-20 files open simultaneously in GVim (more than fits nicely into screen horizontally) and I've enabled tab bar (`set showtabline=1`). I'd like to change the tab bar behaviour so that when I click the arrow button on either end of the tab bar, the tab bar would scroll instead of switching to next/previous tab. Is this possible?

Comment: Beyond reducing the number of tab pages as suggested by Ingo, you should also think about reducing the use of the mouse, as it is usually faster to control it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think this is possible. All aspects of tab pages are described at `:help tabpage`, and I didn't find a setting there.

In general, you should avoid having too many tab pages, because you lose out on opportunities for quick navigation and movement of text across buffers. Things like the quickfix and preview windows always open in window splits, so learn how to use them (and the underlying concepts of windows vs. buffers).

I know that many people today open dozens of tabs in their browsers, but Vim is different. I only use tab pages to separate different workspaces (e.g. edit a mapping in tab 3 while I'm coding in tab 1 and have the documentation in tab 2).